# Equivalent syntax for accessing mutli-dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Going through knr and i've reached multidimensional arrays.

I'm wondering about a couple things:

First.

Suppose i initialize the following array

```
int a[2][4] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Now, i understand this as setting aside 2 blocks of 4*sizeof(int) bytes of contiguous memory. Alright, so then it seems to me like its just a nice way to set aside memory defined multiplicativly. So... Why is the following not true:

```
int a[8] == int[2][4]
```

Second, when i go,

```
int a[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{2,3,4}};
```

Why does this attempt fail

```
a[5] = 22;
```

So what IS a multidimensional array if its not just a contiguous block of memory?

Comment: `int a[2,3]` won't compile.

Comment: captaincurrie,  perhaps you should edit your question detail and fix int a[2, 3]? (as found by alk)

Comment: `int a[8] == int[2][4]` is also not legal C

Comment: where in the c standard does it say a 2D array will have all elements stored in a contiguous block of memory?

Comment: @RedAlert If 1D arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous, then a 1D array that contains arrays should also surely be contiguous.

Comment: `int a[2,3]` is the same as `int a[3]`, unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion about pointers and multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911244/confusion-about-pointers-and-multidimensional-arrays) with a nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963467/694576

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I also thought of this, but a quick test revealed that at least gcc 4.7.2 rejects it with the error `expected ‘]’ before ‘,’ token`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp int a[2,3] is a syntax error, i fixed it about

Comment: @RedAlert K&R 2nd Edition. In sections A7.3.1, "The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))." In section A8.6.2, "It follows from the rules that arrays are stored by rows (last subscript varies fastest)..."

Comment: @user3386109 that applies to 1D arrays. `E1[E2][E3]` is not identical to `*(E1 + E2 + E3)`. You need to deference twice for a 2d array - `*(*(E1 + E2) + E3)`

Comment: @RedAlert See section A8.6.2 for details. It's too long to quote here in its entirety.

Comment: @captaincurrie: Ah, I thought it would have been parsed the same as `int a[(2,3)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
T a[x][y][z];
```

`a`is an array (with `x` elements) of arrays (with `y` elements each) of arrays (with `z` elements each) of type `T`.

**Update**:

An array defined as above indeed is a continous block of memory.

However seeing a line like this

```
T t = b[0][0[0];
```

without knowing how `a` is defined does not necessarily mean `b` is a continous block of memory holding all elements accessable via indexing `b` in 3 dimensions.

Arrays can be scattered.

For example

```
T ** c1 = malloc(x * sizeof(*c1));
for (size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i)
  c1[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(**c1));
```

would allow you to access `c1`'s `x`*`y` elements in exactly the same way as you could do with

```
T c2[x][y];
```

`c2` elements are stored in one continous region of memory, whereas `c1` elements are scattered in `x` regions of size `y`, with an addtional block of memory of size `c1` is `x * sizeof(*c1)` compared to the size of  `c2`.

Comment: These are C arrays, not high-level python arrays. My confusion is born from the 'low-level' arrays in C; "contiguous blocks of memory", not super abstract objects. Is that interpretation wrong for multidimensional arrays? Thats what i'm really wondering

Comment: "high-level", "low-level", "Python" ...? - I don't get you? There is only one way to declare an array in C. @captaincurrie

Comment: I feel that in higher level language, like Python, arrays are much more abstract objects, because they behave that way. Whereas in C, you can't use arrays without understanding there 'low-level' "reality" as 'contiguous blocks of memory'. My confusion is born from failing to understand the low-level reality of C multidimensional arrays

Answer (score 0):

If you have int a[2][4] and you try to access a[1], the a[1] is an **int[]** and not an **int**.

In other words a[1] is an array while a[1][1] is an integer value.

You need to cast in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A multidimensional array *is* just a contiguous block of memory.  However, when you declare a variable, the compiler expects you to use that variable as you've declared it. So if you declare `a` as a two dimensional array with the line

```
   int a[2][4] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

then the compiler is going to treat the variable `a` as a two dimensional array.

If you would like to access that array as a one dimensional array, then you need to declare another variable, e.g.

```
   int *b = (int *)a;
```

Then you can access the elements of the array with code like this

```
   for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
       printf( "%d %d\n", i, b[i] );
```

and the output will be

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 0
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 0
```

Note the zeros at locations 3 and 7.  Those elements are zero because each row of the array was declared to hold 4 items, but the initializer only has 3 items per row. Any unspecified items in the initializer are filled with zeros.